# Non-existence of a holomorphic map on the disc

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, analyticity

Is there a function $f$ that is holomorphic on the punctured unit disc such that $f^{\prime}$ has a pole of order $1$? My answer is: No.

The following post has an answer to my question.

[Show that there is no function $f$ that is analytic in punctured unit disc and $f'$ has a simple pole at $0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240329/show-that-there-is-no-function-f-that-is-analytic-in-punctured-unit-disc-and)

Here's my reasoning:

Let $f$ be such a function. Then $f^{\prime} (z) = \frac{g(z)}{z}$ for some holomorphic function $g$ on the pictured disc and $g(0)$ is NOT equal to $0.$ Now, taking integral both sides along the boundary of a small disc that is contained in the unit disc, we have $0 = g(0),$ which is a contradiction. Is this a valid argument? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get $0=g(0)$?

Comment: The left side of the integral $0$ and the right side is $2 i \pi g(0).$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is there anything wrong with my argument?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f^{\prime}$ has antiderivative $f$.  Then the integral of   $f^{\prime}$ around any closed curve is zero by FTC for contour integral. The only issue is that  $f^{\prime}$ has a pole. So, using FTC might be incorrect.

Comment: Your argument looks fine. I mis-interpreted it at first.

Comment: Thanks so much, Professor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution: if the Laurent series of $f$ is
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n z^n,$$
then the Laurent series of $f'$ will be
$$
f'(z) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n z^{n-1} + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}na_n z^{n-1} =
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n + 1)a_{n+1}z^n + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-2}(n + 1)a_{n+1}z^n.
$$
Also, using integration by parts (["Integration by parts" in complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505857/integration-by-parts-in-complex-analysis/505865)):
$$
2\pi i\,{\rm res}(f',0) = 
\int_\gamma f'(z)1\,dz =
- \int_\gamma f(z)0\,dz =
- \int_\gamma 0\,dz = 0.
$$